# Character sequence UWP [Calculator]

Tags: c#, uwp

I am making a calculator on UWP. My problem is that i need a way to apply an equation to two buttons to convert Celsius to F and vise versa. But my main problem is that i don't know how to cast an Exception correctly if someone types in something like "5+-*/6". The program works well if i try "5--6 = 11" but i dont want it to crash if someone types in too many characters, rather to then just say "Failed" and then reset it.

How should i go about fixing this sequence and also apply the convertion for C and F when i am using a datatable to get my answers?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace Calc
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// 

    
    
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {


        
        public static bool fClick = false; 
        string input = string.Empty;
        string x = string.Empty;
        string y = string.Empty;
        char operation;
        double result = 0.0;


        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text += '1';

          
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text += '2';


        }

        private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text += '3';

        }

        private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text += '4';


        }

        private void Button_Click_4(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text += '5';

        }

        private void Button_Click_5(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text += '6';


        }

        private void Button_Click_6(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text += '7';


        }

        private void Button_Click_7(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text += '8';

        }

        private void Button_Click_8(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text += '9';


        }

        private void Button_Click_9(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text += "42";
     
        }

        private void Button_Click_10(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text += '0';
   
        }

        private void Button_Click_11(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text += '*';

        }

        private void Button_ClickPlus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text += '+';
        }

        private void Button_ClickMinus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text += '-';
        }

        private void Button_ClickTimes(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text += '*';
        }

        private void Button_ClickDEv(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text += '/';
        }

        private void Button_ClickEqual(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
             object q = new DataTable().Compute(textBox.Text, null);
                        textBox.Text = q.ToString();
            }
            catch
            {
                //? 
            }
           
        }

        private void Button_ClickReset(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text = string.Empty;

        }

        private void Button_Click_fc_(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //F to C.
        }

        private void Button_Click_cf_(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //C to F. 
        }
    }
}
```

```
<Page
    x:Class="Calc.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Calc"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="1142" Height="1289">

    <Grid Margin="0,0,10,10">
        <Button Content="1" Margin="113,285,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="64" Width="133" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Button Content="2" Margin="293,285,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="64" Width="134" FontSize="48" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        <Button Content="3" Margin="467,285,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="64" Width="134" FontSize="48" Click="Button_Click_2"/>
        <Button Content="4" Margin="113,377,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="65" Width="133" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_Click_3"/>
        <Button Content="5" Margin="293,381,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="65" Width="134" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_Click_4"/>
        <Button Content="6" Margin="467,381,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="65" Width="134" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_Click_5"/>
        <Button Content="7" Margin="113,472,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="64" Width="133" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_Click_6"/>
        <Button Content="8" Margin="293,472,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="64" Width="134" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_Click_7"/>
        <Button Content="9" Margin="467,472,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="64" Width="134" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_Click_8"/>
        <Button Content="0" Margin="293,563,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="65" Width="134" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_Click_10"/>
        <Button Content="Marcus" Margin="113,563,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="65" Width="133" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_Click_9"/>
        <Button Content="F=M*A" Margin="467,563,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="65" Width="134" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_Click_11"/>
        <Button Content="+" Margin="651,285,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="64" Width="132" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_ClickPlus"/>
        <Button Content="-" Margin="651,381,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="65" Width="132" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_ClickMinus"/>
        <Button Content="*" Margin="651,472,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="64" Width="132" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_ClickTimes"/>
        <Button Content="/" Margin="651,563,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="65" Width="132" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_ClickDEv"/>
        <Button Content="=" Margin="113,651,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="65" Width="488" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_ClickEqual"/>

        <Button Content="Reset" Margin="651,651,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="65" Width="132" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_ClickReset"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="113,63,0,0" Text="" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="190" Width="833" FontSize="72"/>
        <Button Content="F&gt;C" Margin="813,285,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="64" Width="133" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_Click_fc_"/>
        <Button Content="C&gt;F" Margin="813,382,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="64" Width="133" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_Click_cf_"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But my main problem is that i don't know how to cast an Exception correctly if someone types in something like "5+-*/6"

In general, we will input one operator for once, so we need make method to judge if it is only one operator when press `+-*/` button like the following.

```
private void Button_ClickPlus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OnceOperator('+');
}

private char[] coperator = { '+', '-', '*', '/' };
private void OnceOperator(char ope)
{
    var res = coperator.Contains(textBox.Text[textBox.Text.Length - 1]);
    if (res)
    {
        textBox.Text = textBox.Text.Remove(textBox.Text.Length - 1);

    }
    textBox.Text += ope;
}
```

For  convertion for C and F please check the following static method .

```
public static double CelsiusToFahrenheit(string temperatureCelsius)
{
    double celsius = System.Double.Parse(temperatureCelsius);
    return (celsius * 9 / 5) + 32;
}
public static double FahrenheitToCelsius(string temperatureFahrenheit)
{
    double fahrenheit = System.Double.Parse(temperatureFahrenheit);
    return (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add something like this to your operator function (Plus function is showed here)

```
    private void Button_ClickPlus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var last = textBox.Text;
        if (last[last.Length - 1] != '+' || last[last.Length - 1] != '-' || last[last.Length - 1] != '*' || last[last.Length - 1] != '/')
        {
            textBox.Text += '+';
        }
        else
        {
            textBox.Text = last.Remove(last.Length - 1, 1);
            textBox.Text += '+';
        }
    }
```

Comment: That doesnt really work for me, it still just puts in more characters but now it doesnt crash, it just stays there. So example : "5--*/*4"... It doesnt remove the last character when i press a new character button.

Comment: did you copy the code in all other operator functions (only change '+' to '-' or '*' or '/') ?

Comment: Yes i did and i changed it so it would work for each operation. But it doesnt remove the last character.